# Eclipse --launcher.openFile does not open the file

Tags: eclipse, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have been trying to open a file from the command line in a running Eclipse session. Based on the [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html), I should be able to do

```
eclipse --launcher.openFile myfilename
```

However, when I do  this, there is a long pause, and then Eclipse tries to launch a new session. It gives me an error message that the workspace is not available, and then wants me to choose a new workspace.

How do I open a file in the *currently running* Eclipse session, from the commandline?

Comment: Weird, I restarted Eclipse and the problem stopped. That's good, but if anything, makes the situation even weirder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Eclipse Helios (3.6) you don't need special command-line parameters to open files from the OS file explorer or command line (see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=4922). I think you should be able to just do `eclipse myfile.java` (as long as you have associated .java files with Eclipse).

Comment: That's what I was doing before, and it was working, which is why I bothered to look up the other option. I'll try it again and make sure I wasn't goofing up somehow. Maybe I'll restart Eclipse and see what happens.